# A number appears inside a div called wpb_wrapper, when I use a custom shortcode

Tags: shortcode

the page automatically display a number inside a div called wpb_wrapper, when I use a custom shortcode. but its nowhere in my function. When I delete the shortcode the number goes away.

```
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element " >
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        1

    </div>
</div>
```

Any clues?

Is a custom Shortcode to display a grid of post, it contains PHP code, HTML tags and CSS.

```
function millennium_grid(){
   return include("mg-custom-grid.php");

add_shortcode('millennium', 'millennium_grid');
```

Comment: Which shortcode / plugin you are referring to? Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `return` an `include` like that. A successful `include()` itself returns `1`, and since you're returning the return value of `include`, your shortcode is displaying "1".

> Handling Returns: *include* returns *FALSE* on failure and raises a
>   warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file,
>   return *1*.
>
> — http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

If you want to output a template or similar file from  shortcode, you need to capture it with [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php):

```
function millennium_grid() {
    ob_start();

    include 'mg-custom-grid.php';

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'millennium', 'millennium_grid' );
```